# Trying to stick randomly generated numbers into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm working on a project currently that involves taking randomly generated numbers, putting them into an array, then using that array throughout the entire program. It's basically supposed to be a number version of wordle. What I'm stuck on right now it trying to make the function to array connection work, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm in a beginner course for programming, so I'm probably making a lot of dumb mistakes. The purpose of the function is to generate 5 random numbers between 0 and 9. The I'm supposed to take those numbers and stick then into an array. Then the array needs to be saved so it can be used for a game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
//using std::array;

    int getRandomDigit() {
        std::random_device randomSource;
        unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        std::default_random_engine engine(seed);
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniformDist(0,9);

        //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int digits[5] = {getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit()};

        return digits[5];
    }

    //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //int randArray[5] = {getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit()};


int main()
{
    //for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    //int randArray[5] = {getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit(),getRandomDigit()};
    //}
    cout << digits[1] <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far. I compile it, and it gives me an error of "'digits' was not declared in this scope". I'm honestly very lost on how to make this work. The random number generator was given to us by our instructor

Comment: Forget about random numbers, and try returning an array of 1~5 from a function.

Comment: Given the number of mistakes in this code, it may serve you best to make a much smaller, simpler program that works correctly first.  Then carefully expand on that working program, making sure each new addition works correctly.  Fixing the code shown here may involve rewriting practically all of it.  Topics that you will need to get more familiar with include variable scope, variable lifetime, infinite recursion, and out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: Micronag: No point to `std::random_device randomSource;` if you're going to seed the generator with wall clock time.

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation error *"'digits' was not declared in this scope"* is because you are using digits in your main function without declaring it first. You only have it declared in *getRandomDigit()*. Declare your array in *main()* instead and set it to values that are returned from *getRandomDigit()*. Additionally, you can not return an array in C++ directly. Focus on returning a single *int* from the *getRandomDigit()* function and populating your array in *main()*.